# For the purpose of Canadian tax reporting, can buying a business be deducted against personal taxable income?

Tags: taxes, canada

In Canada, can buying a business be deducted against personal taxable income as other business related expenses would, if one is running it as a sole proprietorship?

Comment: Buying a business is not a business expense.

Comment: not even if one has existing business, and buys an another existing business to add to their own?

Comment: of course not. That is called *investment* and is not tax deductible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will be able to claim it as an expense on your taxes, but not all in the current year. It is split into three categories:

1. Current Expenses - Assets purchased such as inventory would be able to be claimed in the current year.
2. Assets - Vehicles, Buildings, and equipment can be depreciated over time based on the value you purchased them for and the CCA class.
3. Goodwill - In tax terms this is the value of the business purchase that is not eligible in 1 or 2 and is called Eligible Capital Property. This can be expensed over time.

From info at CRA website: http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/bsnss/tpcs/lf-vnts/byng/menu-eng.html